# Angular - Why my variable is "undefined" after subscribe to API?

Tags: angular, api, subscribe

After I call my API service, I have a undefined variable in the template, but I see the expected result in the console.

There is my VideoComponent that called API

```
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {
  video: Video = new Video();

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.apiService.getOneVideoByID(params['id']).subscribe((video: Video) => {
        this.video = video;
        console.log(this.video);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

There is my API service:

```
export class ApiService {
  PHP_API_SERVER = 'http://127.0.0.1/TutoWorld/backend/api';
  private headers;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  }


  getOneVideoByID(id: number): Observable<Video> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Video>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/readOne?id=${id}`,{headers: this.headers});
  }
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="block5"></div>
<div id="videoContainer">
  <p>video title: {{video.titre}}  </p>
</div>
```

And my Video Model:

```
export class Video {
  id: number;
  url: string;
  titre: string;
  langue: string;
  description: string;
  date_creation: string;
  date_ajout: string;
  auteur_id: number;
  auteur_nom: string;
}
```

If someone can help me to solve this issue, would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: What is undefined? `console.log(this.video)`?

Comment: No, it,s when i try to access in the template: <p>video title: {{video.titre}}  </p>. in the console.log i see the good result

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. What do you see if you do `<p>video: {{ video | json }} </p>. And do you see `video title: ` present in the view?

Comment: Nothing change when adding pipe. There is a screenshot of my page: https://zupimages.net/up/20/09/6xay.png

Comment: I suggest you to transform that definition to an `interface` instead of a `class`. You are not using a constructor and interfaces don't get transpiled in javascript.

Comment: I will use constructor when I ll implement post method

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the console, it seems to be an array.

I would also avoid nested subscribes, try this:

```
  import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; // this import could be wrong, double check
.....
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap(params => this.apiService.getOneVideoByID(params['id'])),
    ).subscribe((video: Video) => {
      this.video = video[0];
      console.log(this.video);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have this error: TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, Video>'.

Comment: I forgot an ending bracket on the switchmap, check now

Comment: Great, it's working but i have had an <iframe> in my html and now i have an other error message: https://zupimages.net/up/20/09/cik2.png.                                             There is my Iframe code: <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{getVideoID(video.url) | safe}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's working but i have had an  in my html and now i have an other error message: https://zupimages.net/up/20/09/cik2.png

There is my Iframe code:

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{getVideoID(video.url) | safe}}"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
```

and my GetVideoID code:

```
getVideoID(url: string) {
    return this.apiService.youtube_parser(url);
  }
```

```
  youtube_parser(url) {
    let regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    let match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match && match[7].length == 11) ? match[7] : false;
  }
```

The Pipe code too:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, url)
  }
}
```

Comment: got 2 : "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined" and "unsafe value used in a resource URL context". You can see it on the screenshot

Comment: The first is normal i think: need time time to get url from api but i don't understand the second with Unsafe value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456881/angular-why-my-variable-is-undefined-after-subscribe-to-api/60457648?noredirect=1#comment106954257_60457648
Maybe change it to `[src] = "url | safe"` and assign `url` to the embedded youtube URL.

Comment: Thanks it works but i had to change the return of my SafePipe class too by:            "return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);" and now it's ok. Thx

Answer (score 0):

To answer initial question here, I must say you treating a response from API which is array as a single instance. Thats why you get it undefined :)